# Barcode Scanner wont scan after using DisplayActionSheet

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

My Zxing ScannerView won't scan after using a DisplayActionSheet.

I am writing a barcode scanner app in Xamarin Forms, it is using the zxing.net.mobile library.

I would like to allow the user to choose if there is another item to be scanned (also adds a delay between pages), so I throw up a DisplayActionSheet. The popup works and upon clicking "Yes", it creates the new page and everything looks good but then the scanner doesn't scan...

I remove the DisplayActionSheet and the next page opens immediately after scanning the first device. This typically causes the program to scan the same barcode for both devices, though it does scan...

```
private void scanner_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(result.Text + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Scan Hard Drive?", null, null, "Yes", "No");
        if (action == "Yes")
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new HDDScanner());
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(HDDfile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(" " + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Steven! What does the HDDScanner class look like? Could you please share more of your code?

Comment: Try taking async out of the "Device.InvokeOnMainThread()" and add async to your function "private async void scanner_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)"